# C warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast / pointer to integer array

Tags: c, pointers, tcp, casting, pthreads

I'm trying to make a chatroom using TCP/IP in C but every new client is a new thread. The clients have to communicate with each other with the server. I have a problem when creating a new thread.

When calling `pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, messenger, (void*)client_socket)`, I'm trying to pass the socket descriptor of the new client and add it in an integer array. But no matter what I try, I get this warning:

> assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Here's the code I'm having trouble with. There is a global int variable called `users` in the `main` function:

```
users = 0;
int new_socket;
int *clinet_socket;

new_socket = accept(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen);
client_socket = &new_socket;

pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, messenger, (void*)client_socket)
```

Here is the `messenger` function:

```
void *messenger(void *sockel){
   unsigned int (*sockerde)[30];

   (*sockerde)[users] = (unsigned int(*))&sockel;
   users++;
}
```

The point is to keep an array with the socket descriptors of all connected clients in order to use it later on.

Comment: Why your function definition "int *clinet_socket;" can't be "void *clinet_socket" ?

Comment: Multiple problems with the `messenger` function: 1) The variable `sockel` is a pointer, `&sockel` is a pointer to the pointer. 2) You define `sockerde` as a *pointer* to an array of `30` unsigned integers, not as an array of 30 pointers (if that's what you really wanted). 3) You never initialize the pointer `sockerde`, so dereferencing it is *undefined behavior*. 4) `(*sockerde)[users]` is an `unsigned int` while `(unsigned int(*))&sockel` is a pointer, and this is where the warning message comes from.

Comment: There are other possible problems as well, for example one that depends on the life-time of the `new_socket` variable compared to the life-time of the thread.

Comment: All in all, you probably should take a few steps back, and go back to a beginners book or tutorial and read more about pointers and how they work.

Comment: Oh and lastly, when using `pthread_create` it's usually one of the very few times where it's considered okay to cast a value to a pointer, and in the function do the opposite cast. Like e.g. `pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, messenger, (void *) (intptr_t) new_socket)`, and in the function `int sock = (int) (intptr_t) sockel;`

Answer (score 1):

The part you're having trouble with is the least of your problems.

- You're not doing error checks.
- You're passing the socket value by reference but you did in no way ensure the `new_socket` value stays stable before the new thread picks it up.
- you're assigning through the `unsigned int (*sockerde)[30];` array pointer, which is pointing nowhere!
- you're accessing a global from multiple threads without doing any synchronization

and finally

- you're casting the address of a local parameter (no point in doing this) to  `unsigned int*` using a weird parenthesizing style and then you try to assign it, through an invalid pointer, to an `unsigned int`, which is what's causing the type error.

Maybe pick up a book?